# Change CSS of an linked div/id

Tags: html, css

I link to a page like page.html#id so the page is automatically focused at this id.

How do i do this in CSS that only the div with the id from the URL gets for example a yellow background?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, add style depending on `href=""`?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:target` pseudo selector.

http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: this is awesome, did not know.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
I just have to wait 10 minutes before i can accept the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - didn't know about `:target`. That answer is better!

You could listen for the `hashchange` event, detect the current hash and apply a class to the corresponding element:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {

  // Remove .active from any currently active elements
  var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  for(var i = 0; i < active.length; ++i) {
    active[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
});
```

If you need to support [browsers that do not support classList](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), there are plenty of [alternatives](http://toddmotto.com/creating-jquery-style-functions-in-javascript-hasclass-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/xFkFP/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the hash value and style it using JavaScript:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //the variable without hash sign.
    document.getElementById(hash).style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: document.querySelector(window.location.hash).style.background = "yellow";

Comment: @Michael That is also a good idea but be sure it is not compatible with IE<8

Comment: @Michael IE<8 means below Internet Explorer 8